# Tableau - restrict access for specific filter

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, restriction

I'm working with Tableau - and I have a workbook that hold Cost values for many departments, I want to give limited access to this workbook for each person.
I have a filter for "Department" - and I want to give access to let's say 2 out of 10 available values to a a specific user (and not to all 10)
How can it be done without duplicating the same workbook, and publish it with different default filters?

Thanks

Comment: use a combination of set and USERNAME() filter

Comment: In the Tableau documentation, search for user filters

Answer (score 0):

[image: steps to create filter in desktop]

- Ensure that those two users have been added to the server.
- In Tableau Desktop, navigate to Server, create a user filter, select the user, and map the departments according to your specific requirements.
- publish the workbook to server
- Subsequently, log in to your server.
- Select the three dots icon next to the workbook that you want to apply restrictions to.
- Select the relevant permissions and configure restrictions according to your requirements.